# "eval: Attempt to modify read-only object" when setcdr to magic-fallback-mode-alist

Tags: pure-storage

I try to replace `html-mode` with `web-mode`:

```
(ignore-errors (require 'web-mode))

(when (featurep 'web-mode)
  (mapc (lambda (spec)
           (when (eq (cdr spec) 'html-mode) (setcdr spec 'web-mode)))
        magic-fallback-mode-alist))
```

and get error:

```
progn: Attempt to modify read-only object: ("\\(?:<\\?xml[  
]+[^>]*>\\)?[   
]*<\\(?:!--\\(?:[^-]\\|-[^-]\\)*-->[    
]*<\\)*\\(?:!DOCTYPE[   
]+[^>]*>[   
]*<[    
]*\\(?:!--\\(?:[^-]\\|-[^-]\\)*-->[     
]*<\\)*\\)?[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]" . html-mode)
```

How can I modify `html-mode` to `web-mode`?

---

We have in `lisp/files.el`:

```
(defvar magic-fallback-mode-alist
  (purecopy ... ))
```

in `src/data.c`:

```
DEFUN ("setcdr", Fsetcdr, Ssetcdr, 2, 2, 0,
       doc: /* Set the cdr of CELL to be NEWCDR.  Returns NEWCDR.  */)
  (register Lisp_Object cell, Lisp_Object newcdr)
{
  CHECK_CONS (cell);
  CHECK_IMPURE (cell, XCONS (cell));
  XSETCDR (cell, newcdr);
  return newcdr;
}
```

in `src/puresize.h`:

```
/* Signal an error if OBJ is pure.  PTR is OBJ untagged.  */

#define puresize_h_CHECK_IMPURE(obj, ptr) \
  (PURE_P (ptr) ? pure_write_error (obj) : (void) 0)

INLINE void
CHECK_IMPURE (Lisp_Object obj, void *ptr)
{
  puresize_h_CHECK_IMPURE (obj, ptr);
}
```

From `(info "(elisp) Pure Storage")`:

> Pure storage is used for certain data in the preloaded
>   standard Lisp files—data that should never change during actual use of
>   Emacs.

---

Emacs have no a way to check if object is in pure storage from Elisp ((

Answer (score 3):

```el
(require 'subr-x)
(when-let (elt (rassq 'html-mode magic-fallback-mode-alist))
  (push (cons (car elt) 'web-mode) magic-fallback-mode-alist))
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to politza's answer, another approach can be:

```
(defalias 'html-mode 'web-mode)
```

this will simply redirect all uses of `html-mode` to `web-mode`, regardless if it comes from `magic-fallback-mode-alist` or `auto-mode-alist` or ...

Answer (score 0):

Because C code doesn't expose `CHECK_IMPURE` macro to Elisp I make silly check and copy pure object to normal object with `copy-tree`:

```
(when (cl-some (lambda (spec) (eq (cdr spec) 'html-mode))
               magic-fallback-mode-alist)
  (setq magic-fallback-mode-alist (copy-tree magic-fallback-mode-alist))
  (mapc (lambda (spec) (when (eq (cdr spec) 'html-mode) (setcdr spec 'web-mode)))
        magic-fallback-mode-alist))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just push a new entry onto `magic-fallback-mode-alist`?

Comment: Have you seen regex for `DOCTYPE`? I am afraid this value complexity...